# django-pyodbc and pervasive database

Tags: django-models

Hi There is a way to use django-pyodbc with pervasive database ? I try different settings but when I try to inspectdb to create a model from the database it shows me this error but I can create querys in pervasive with python pyodbc.

`('42000', '[42000] [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC 
    Engine Interface]Invalid SET statement. (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:
    Django Version: 1.6.6
    Exception Type: ProgrammingError
    Exception Value:
    ('42000', '[42000] [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine               Interface]Invalid SET statement. 
   (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
    Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\base.py in _cursor, line 296
    Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
    Python Version: 2.7.8

```
cursor.execute("SET DATEFORMAT Ymd; SET DATEFIRST %s" % self.datefirst)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive]                     [ODBC Engine Interface]Invalid SET statement. (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')`
```

and this is the piece of the error when I try to run inspectdb on the database.

According to the main problem is in this file base.py line 296 is some problem with a set statement on the odbc driver this is piece of the code on base.py I try to comment but after another thing shows up.

```
`cursor.execute("SET DATEFORMAT Ymd; SET DATEFIRST %s" % self.datefirst)
        if self.ops.sql_server_ver < 2005:
            self.creation.data_types['TextField'] = 'ntext'
            self.features.can_return_id_from_insert = False

        ms_sqlncli = re.compile('^((LIB)?SQLN?CLI|LIBMSODBCSQL)')
        self.drv_name = self.connection.getinfo(Database.SQL_DRIVER_NAME).upper()

        # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx
        if self.ops.sql_server_ver >= 2005 and ms_sqlncli.match(self.drv_name) and                                         self.MARS_Connection:
            # How to to activate it: Add 'MARS_Connection': True
            # to the DATABASE_OPTIONS dictionary setting
            self.features.can_use_chunked_reads = True`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put single quote around %s:

```
cursor.execute("SET DATEFORMAT Ymd; SET DATEFIRST '%s'" % self.datefirst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your access rights. The error message indicates a syntax error but according to [mssql support site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713611(v=vs.85).aspx), error code 42000 is either "Syntax error or access violation".